# Maven Systempath not working as expected

Tags: maven

I have specified following dependencies(For example  mentioned one here) in pom.xml which will look for saaj.jar under the specified sytempath and Maven used to pick it from same path  and working fine.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>saaj</groupId>
<artifactId>saaj</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/saaj.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Now I have moved to windows 7 and Spring  Tool suite 2.7.1 version(Previously Win XP and Spring older vesion). In this new setup am getting below error.

```
Missing artifact saaj:saaj:jar:1.0:system
```

Now, It is looking for saaj-1.0.jar instead of saaj.jar and under the folder ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/saaj/saaj/1.0/ instead of ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/.

Why is it so? Please provide the solution where my previous setup should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid systemPath, you must create a local repository like :

this is you pom file :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>tiago.medici</groupId>
      <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

on project you create a lib folder to put your jar and maven pom file generated from

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\tiago.medici-0.0.1.jar -DgroupId=tiago.medici -DartifactId=eureka -Dversion=0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

tiago.medici-0.0.1.pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tiago.medici</groupId>
  <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `system` scope. It was meant for *system* provided libraries. Given the path you gave for it, you are obviously creating a web application.

Use a war project and specify your dependencies with `provided` scope if they're already available (e.g. because they are provided by your application server) or without a scope specification otherwise. Maven will take care of packaging your project dependency in a correct way, both for Eclipse development and for deployment in your application server.